# MIPS array indexing using a displacement in lw for a known constant index?

Tags: assembly, mips, micro-optimization

I am trying to translate from C this line of code of a nested array `p=A[B[6]]` that I've found on the book I'm studying MIPS from.
Because I am pretty sure that the solution from the book is wrong or, at least, much more complicated than what it needs to be.

The base address of the array A[] is stored in the register $s1, the base address of B[] is stored in $s2 and the value of g is stored in $s0.

My translation of `p=A[B[6]]` would be (please tell me if it is correct):

```
lw $t0, 24($s2) #load from memory B[6] in the register $t0
sll $t0, $t0, 2 #$t0=$t0*4
add $t0, $t0, $s1 #add to $t0 the address of A[B[6]]
lw $t0, 0($t0) #$t0=A[B[6]]
```

While instead the book (which is full of other errors) offers this solution:

```
addi $t0, $0, 6
sll sll $t0, $t0 2 
add $t1, $s2, $t0 
lw $t2, 0 ($t1)
sll $t2, $t2 2 
add $t3, $s1, $t2
lw $s0, 0 ($t3)
```

Is my code correct or is the book right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both versions are logically correct; the only problem with the book version is that it's very inefficient.

It fails to optimize based on the fact that `6` is an assemble-time constant, so the `6*4` can be an immediate displacement in the `lw`, instead of calculated at runtime in a register and added to the base separately.

`lw` has room for 16 bits of immediate offset; it's silly not to take advantage and restrict yourself to only ever using `0`.  It's an I-type instruction for a reason, dedicating lots of coding space to allowing a large offset.

Other than that your versions are equivalent.  The book version calculates `6<<2` in a register and adds it to the base of `B` (`$s2`).  It gets the initial `6` into a register by adding to the zero-register.

Both yours and the book's use `add` instead of `addu`.  Not sure why you want to trap on signed overflow, especially when doing address math.  C compilers normally always use `addu`.  (Signed overflow is undefined behaviour in C, but compiler developers know that it's usually more useful / expected for it to silently wrap than to raise an exception.)